# How to make this big image side-by-side with smaller image?

Tags: html, css

The desired outcome I want to appear on my html5 page is like this;

[image]

However, the one I have now on my html page is like this;

[image]

The html code I have is like this;

```
<form data-ng-controller="MyController">
    <switch name="onOff" ng-model="onOff" on="on" off="off"></switch>
</form>

<img src = "img/tube.jpg"/>
```

The switch icon is created from angular-ui-switch. How should I make the tube positioned beside the switch and make it about the same size as the switch?

EDIT: Thanks to the comments, there is a close solution now.

```
<form data-ng-controller="MyController">
    <switch name="onOff" ng-model="onOff" on="on" off="off"></switch>
</form>

<img src = "img/tube.jpg" height=80 width=80>
```

The tube is smaller now. However, it is placed below the switch and not beside the switch. How to make it appear beside the switch?

Comment: This is basically a `CSS` issue.. So can you just show us some `CSS`  or a **`jsfiddle`** would be great..

Comment: give the same height and display:inline-block; to both object.

Comment: set fixed height and width of image and apply float:left on both images

Comment: <img src = "img/tube.jpg"/ height=xxx width=yyy> this  will do your part

Comment: What i can add is it's not a good practice to use big images when you need small. One reason to do it - when you use this image in several places with different sizes.                                 So it's advisable to resize your image to the size you need before you upload it to website.

Comment: @ Ankur140290, thanks! Solution is very close now. The tube now has become smaller. However, it is placed below the switch. How can I make it appear beside the switch?

Comment: just use <form style="display: inline-block;" ...>...</form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inline-block` element to display image right of switch

```
<form data-ng-controller="MyController" style="display: inline-block;">
    <switch name="onOff" ng-model="onOff" on="on" off="off"></switch>
</form>

<img src = "img/tube.jpg" height="100px" width="100px"/>
```

Comment: So, to make images appear side-by-side, is it advisable to always use `style="display: inline-block;"`?

Comment: Happy to help :) , By default form element are type block that means any html element after form tag will appear from next line i.e., below form element by making it display:inline-block forces the next html element to appear just after form tag if there is space

Comment: However img element by default 'display:inline' that means if you will add one more img tag it will by default appear next to each other provided there is space

Answer (score 1):

You can use max width to rescale your image, example

```css
#max {
  max-width:100px;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXsb3.jpg">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXsb3.jpg" id="max">
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add width or height in your img tag

```
<img src = "img/tube.jpg" width="75px"/>
```